# ASP.NET TextBoxFor - prevent attribute value escaping

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a TextBoxFor like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Test, new { data_binding = "value:Test,events:['keyup']" })
```

The output is:

```
<input data-binding="value:Test,events:[&#39;keyup&#39;]" id="Test" name="Test" placeholder="" type="text" />
```

The ' around keyup are replaced with &# 39; .

How do I prevent escaping/sanitazing of the attribute value?

Comment: if i were you i will split the data-binding to data-binding-value and data-binding-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just had a look of generated view source of the page. View Source will add the unicode chars for `'` and `"`

No need to worry. check how it is rendered in DOM using Firebug.

If you want to access that data value in javascript, you can try like below

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, 
     new { data_binding = "value:Test,events:['keyup']", @id="test" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert($('#test').data('binding'));
    });
</script>
```